# How to construct FluentIterable from a single element?

Tags: guava

This is the API from guava `FluentIterable.of(E[] e)`

I hope it's like `FluentIterable.of(E... e)` , so I can build it from a single element.

Do I miss something or there's some special reason to avoid this?

Now, my code is

```
FluentIterable.from(Lists.newArrayList(singleElement));//UGLY
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this will be in Guava 20.0:
https://github.com/google/guava/commit/b01e8df8a7ffdcd3d52c960aadb044fefaafc8ba#diff-5801d092caa7673b9c43544c7ad01d4d

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like it is coming (see [Improve FluentIterable.of to take variable # of arguments. by scr · Pull Request #2136 · google/guava](https://github.com/google/guava/pull/2136); see also [Factory method to create a FluentIterable from an array · Issue #1070 · google/guava](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1070)).

Maybe in Guava 20?